# method select for MultiSelectComboBox not working

Tags: java, vaadin, multi-select

I have a `MultiSelectComboBox` but when trying to select some items through its `select()` method nothing happens.

My code looks as follows:

```
Binder<Technology> binder = new BeanValidationBinder<>(Technology.class);
MultiSelectComboBox<TechnologyLabel> multiComboBox = new MultiSelectComboBox<>("Labels");

binder
                .forField(this.multiComboBox)
                .bind(Technology::getLabels, Technology::setLabels);

        List<TechnologyLabel> labelList = technologyLayout.technologyLabelService.getTechnologyLabels(technology);
        List<Label> containedLabels = new ArrayList<>();
        for (var tl : labelList) {
            containedLabels.add(tl.getLabel());
        }
        List<Label> labels = labelService.findAllLabels();

        for (var label : labels) {
            if (!containedLabels.contains(label)) {
                labelList.add(new TechnologyLabel(technology, label));
            }
        }
        multiComboBox.setItems(labelList);
        multiComboBox.setItemLabelGenerator(TechnologyLabel::getLabelName);
        note.setMaxHeight("10em");

        multiComboBox.select(labelList.get(0);
```

What I do above is querying my `ManyToMany` relation to find all `labels` given the `technology`. Then I find all the `labels` and create a `list` from that. Lastly, I try to select first item of the list, but it does not show a tick next to it.

Comment: Does `TechnologyLabel` have proper setup for equals and hashCode?

Comment: @cfrick thank you good sir <3. I completely forgot about it

Comment: Is you issue solve? If yes, please add it as the answer or delete the question

Answer (score 0):

Using @cfrick as answer basically and all credits go to him, but i wanted to leave a proper answer. I had the same problem, i defined the `equals` and `hashcode` method in my `TechnologyLabel` and it started working. i only had to compare by `id` in my code.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    TechnologyLabel technologyLabel = (TechnologyLabel) obj;
    return Objects.equals(id, technologyLabel.id);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id);
}
```